# Error using test containers for Oracle on the Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, testcontainers

There is a need to add the use of test container to a project written with spring 1.5.9.RELEASE.  Oracle is used as the image, but at the time of initialization I get an error:

> exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/bh/fdcfxxzj3_ncnvtny6gq780sf1snjv/T/jna--920191490/jna1331380426531635068.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/bh/fdcfxxzj3_ncnvtny6gq780sf1snjv/T/jna--920191490/jna1331380426531635068.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/bh/fdcfxxzj3_ncnvtny6gq780sf1snjv/T/jna--920191490/jna1331380426531635068.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have (i386,x86_64), need (arm64e)))

I use Mac with Apple Silicon chip.

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class ConfigOracleTestContainers {
    @Bean
    public OracleContainer testContainer() {

        OracleContainer oracleContainer = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:18.4.0-slim")
                .withDatabaseName("testDB")
                .withUsername("testUser")
                .withPassword("testPassword");

        return oracleContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource(OracleContainer container) {

        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(container.getJdbcUrl())
                .username(container.getUsername())
                .password(container.getPassword())
                .driverClassName(container.getDriverClassName())
                .build();
    }
}
```

I installed 'colima' and I performed command

```bash
colima start
```

But I get an error:

> ERROR o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy [] - Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration.

Is it possible that docker-images oracle are not compatible with Apple Silicon Mac of this MAC?

Have any ideas or an example of how to fix it.

Comment: *Is it possible that docker-images oracle are not compatible with Apple Silicon Mac of this MAC?* that is exactly what that error message is telling you.

Comment: Oracle database only runs on x86 architecture.